# How to get a mouse working in my own operating system? INT 33h doesn't work outside of EMU8086

Tags: assembly, mouse, interrupt, x86-16, osdev

I have developed an own OS entirely in Assembly, now I want to implement a mouse driver because I see that the INT 33h in Windows with EMU8086 works but when I boot from floppy it doesn't work. I have tried either USB and PS/2 mouse, same result. Can anyone explain me what I must do in order to make the OS recognize the mouse ?

Comment: I did not do x86 hardware programming for the last 10 years, but is the INT 33h really provided by the BIOS nowadays? I thought it is just a protocol between applications and the mouse driver, not something that works out of the box if you are writing your own OS.

Comment: You're right, INT 33h is a DOS interrupt not a BIOS interrupt. However I found something about INT 15h

Comment: no idea, but +1 for your work

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043732/accessing-the-mouse-via-assembly-x86

Comment: I'd also look into how Linux does it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175960/which-drivers-are-used-by-usb-mouse-in-linux-kernel

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't assume that the old BIOS "pointing device" functions (e.g. "int 0x15, ax = 0xC200") work either.

If you're writing an OS, you need to write device drivers for the OS. This means writing a full USB stack and drivers for USB keyboard/mouse; and writing drivers for PS/2 keyboard and mouse. See http://wiki.osdev.org/Mouse_Input .

Comment: Now that I think about it, I seem to recall that the Int 15h pointing device routines go all the way back to the original PC or maybe the PCjr and were there for joysticks.  While it's possible they support a mouse on newer machines, it's more likely that they don't.