# Game in assembler program (in graphic mode) screen

Tags: assembly, mouse

I tried to do a game in assembler program (in graphic mode), in which I've got proc of some creature that moves around the screen. 
The thing is, I want to add a mouse on the screen, and a code that in which every time someone clicks on the right button of the mouse, the creature will disapear. I have a proc of disapearing the creature, I just need to call her. Someone can help me?

Comment: You haven't specified which OS you'r targetting. If it's DOS you'll have to look up the appropriate interrupts to use (it's 33h IIRC); if it's Windows you should use the Windows API; if it's Linux/BSD/OSX then I've no idea.

Comment: It's DOS. I've used some of the 33h interrupts to show the mouse itself on the screen.The problem is that I didn't find any interrupts. Could you please get me a link to some of them?

Comment: Just google "int 33h".

Comment: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-33.htm ... But maybe you like to use an own PS2-mousehandler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043732/accessing-the-mouse-via-assembly-x86

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure that your *proc of disapearing the creature* terminates with a `RETF` instruction.
2. Then use the **Set User-Defined Event Handler** function of the `int 33h` mouse functions:

   ```
   mov ax, 000Ch            ;Function number
   mov cx, 0008h            ;Call mask: bit 3=ON means RightButtonPressed
   mov dx, Offset of your procedure
   mov es, Segment of your procedure
   int 33h
   ```

It would be best if your procedure preserved the flags and all registers it uses.
You can only rely on the CS segment register when you get invoked. The AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, and DI registers all have mouse-related values but they are of no importance for your present purpose.